# connect to mssql database via sqlsrv_connect() - PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm attempting to connect to a 2005 Microsoft sql database using PHP by using the `sqlsrv_connect()` function. alas, the function returns false, and im not sure why.

```
<?php
$myServer = "MAZE.jpc.wa.edu.au.local";
$myUser = "myUsername";
$myPass = "myPassword";
$myDB = "John Paul College";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$myDB, "UID" => $myUser, "PWD" => $myPass);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo); //returns false
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "failed connection";
}

$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name= 'admin'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
if(sqlsrv_fetch($stmt) ===false)
{
    echo "couldn't fetch data"; 
}
$name = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt,0);
echo $name;
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
?>
```

Does anyone know why I can't connect?
Thanks.

Edit.

Ok, well, i was able to bring up an error message thanks to the other guys answer, which states

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
        [1] => -49 [code] => -49
        [2] => This extension requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client (SP1 or later)
                or the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server.
                Neither of those ODBC Drivers are currently installed.
                Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC driver
                for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 
        [message] => This extension requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client (SP1 or later) 
              or the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server.
              Neither of those ODBC Drivers are currently installed. 
              Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC driver 
              for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 
        [1] => 0 [code] => 0 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified 
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

I'm not entirely sure how to go about fixing this issue. I'm using XAMPP as my test webserver, php version 5.3 and the following .dlls
`php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll`
and
`php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll`

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: is your database named `John Paul College`? with all those spaces? then i think you should be using `$myDB = "[John Paul College]";`

Comment: You need to download and install the drivers like the error message says. It pretty much explains how to solve your problem ?

Comment: doesn't it clearly stated you need `SQL Server 2008` or higher? If you are still using SQL server 2005 try using [mssql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option of upgrading the server. I'm stuck with 2005. Does anyone know what drivers I should be using if im currently using the wrong ones?

Comment: Check my comment above. You cannot use sqlsrv_*. The mssql is still available even though it is severely deprecated like SQL server 2005.

Comment: I've already tried mssql. it was completely removed in php 5.3, so it's not available to me. If it were, that would make my life a hell of a lot easier :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you display the connection error using sqlsrv_errors(). Please see the following implementation.

```
<?php
   $serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName

   // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
   // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
   }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
?>
```

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Download the SQL Native Client as the error message suggests. This is separate from SQL Server and a requirement for this driver to work correctly. Lesson learned from building an implementation of sqlsrv in an IIS environment