# sqlsrv_connect cannot connect to localhost

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I am trying to connect to `MSSQL` using `sqlsrv_connect()` however it is not working. I am getting a weird error:

```
/var/www/html/dir/mssql_conn.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/dir/mssql_conn.php: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/var/www/html/dir/mssql_conn.php: line 5: `$conn_array = array ('
```

My code is:

```
$conn_array = array (
    "UID" => "",
    "PWD" => "",
    "Database" => "dbName",
);


    $conn = sqlsrv_connect('(local)', $conn_array);


    if ($conn) {
        echo "connected";

        if(($result = sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.tblp")) !== false){

            while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $result )) {
                  echo $obj->colName.'<br />';
            }
        }


    } else {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

I've tried `localhost\sqlexpress, 8357`, `serv.domain.tld\sqlexpress, 8357` too and nothing works.

Form the outside there is a port. But I don't think that would apply from the inside would it?

Any help how I can actually connect?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308120/connect-to-mssql-database-via-sqlsrv-connect-php

Comment: @RavinderReddy Kay. I saw the selected answer. Nothing different than what I have. Maybe its the stupid server name thing...what exactly goes there? Its on the same server so `(local)`?

Comment: A silly question but did you add `<?php` opening tag at the beginning, or is it correctly added?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the connection by the below code

```
$serverName = "(local)\sqlexpress";  
$conn_array = array("UID" => "",
"PWD" => "",
"Database" => "dbName"
); // Provide the valid details 

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $conn_array);  
if( $conn === false )  
die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) );

function FormatErrors( $errors )  
{  
    /* Display errors. */  
    echo "Error information: <br/>";  

    foreach ( $errors as $error )  
    {  
        echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error['SQLSTATE']."<br/>";  
        echo "Code: ".$error['code']."<br/>";  
        echo "Message: ".$error['message']."<br/>";  
    }  
}
```

For more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-sqlsrv-driver

Comment: Error again: `/var/www/html/dir/mssql_conn.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/dir/mssql_conn.php: line 12: =: command not found
/var/www/html/dir/mssql_conn.php: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/var/www/html/dir/mssql_conn.php: line 13: `$connectionOptions = array("UID" => “user”, "PWD" => “pass”,”Database" => “database” ); // Provide the valid details '`

Comment: It seems the issues is not with connection. Its something else. Print array by adding  print_r($conn_array); exit; after array declaration.

Comment: Its not printing them out. Even when they are commented out they are still causing a problem...